# How to get field name using the improved MySQL (MySQLI)?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

The following is a PHP code that I'm using to convert a MySQL table into csv output. However, I couldn't figure out how to convert MySQL_field_name to the equivalent in MySQLI. Can anyone assist?

```
<?php
/* vars for export */
// database record to be exported
$db_record = 'manufacturing_';
// optional where query
$where = 'WHERE 1 ORDER BY 1';
// filename for export
$csv_filename = 'db_export_'.$db_record.'_'.date('Y-m-d').'.csv';
// database variables
$hostname = "localhost";
$user = "XXXXXXXXX";
$password = "XXXXXXXXX";
$database = "XXXXXXXXX";
// Database connecten voor alle services
$connection = mysqli_connect($hostname, $user, $password) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());

mysqli_select_db($connection, $database) or die ('Could not select database ' . mysqli_error());
// create empty variable to be filled with export data
$csv_export = '';
// query to get data from database
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM ".$db_record." ".$where);
$field = mysqli_num_fields($query);
// create line with field names
for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
  $csv_export.= mysqli_field_name($connection, $query,$i).';';
}
// newline (seems to work both on Linux & Windows servers)
$csv_export.= '
';
// loop through database query and fill export variable
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($connection, $query)) {
  // create line with field values
  for($i = 0; $i < $field; $i++) {
    $csv_export.= '"'.$row[mysqli_field_name($connection, $query,$i)].'";';
  } 
  $csv_export.= '
';  
}
// Export the data and prompt a csv file for download
header("Content-type: text/x-csv");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".$csv_filename."");
echo($csv_export);
?>
```

Error Message:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mysqli_field_name()

Answer (score -1):

You can get this infos from **INFORMATION_SCHEMA** with a query like this. you only must change the TABLE_SCHEMA and the TABLE_NAME

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE TABLE_NAME ='owner' AND TABLE_SCHEMA='test'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```